# Google charts Timeline

Tags: javascript, charts, timeline

I have a timeline chart with 5 rows, and I have defined the color for each row:

```
var options = {         
        colors: ['#FFF000', '#0094FF', '#FF6A00', '#26BA00', '#FF0000'],         
        timeline: {            
            colorByRowLabel: true
        }
};
```

I would like to know if it is possible to have bars of different colors in the same row.
I want to combine row 1 and row 2 in one single row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a `groupByRowLabel` option which could match your needs, take a look at it in [the doc](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline).

More specifically, it says :

> When there are four columns in a timeline dataTable, the first is
>   interpreted as the row label, the second as the bar label, and the
>   third and fourth as start and end.

So if you set the bars you want to have different colors with the same row name, and `groupByRowLabel` option, they'll appear on the same line with different colors.

However, it seems logically incompatible with your `colorByRowLabel` option.

Comment: I am already using that option, my problem is that I need to have both colors, yellow and blue, in the same row.

Comment: @JuanAlberto Is there something that keeps you from naming the rows alike?

Comment: not really, but if I do that,I would see all the bars in the same row but also in the same color, I need to have them in different colors, because they represent different things.

Comment: Row labels and individual bar labels are different things and can indeed have different values. In the above linked doc, see namely [this part](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#putting-bars-on-one-row).

Comment: I was not able to accomplish what I needed using the Google Chart Timeline, but I found another library, http://visjs.org/ it has more configuration options and I was able to have items with different colors in the same row.